# script openWindow Move to a specific location Popup in a popup asp.net mvc,

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

**I want to move this open window to the left side of the screen and not in the center of the screen.Any help please?**
//Open Window

```
    function openWindowText() {
        var tries = $('#ImageTry').val();
        var question = $('#CurrentQuestion').val();

        var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
            title: "Enlarged Text",
            html: "<div id='divText" + question + '-' + tries + "'></div>",
            contentUrl: "",
            actions: ["Maximize", "Close"],
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            onRefresh: function (e) {
                windowElement.center();
            },
            onClose: function () { }
        }).data('tWindow').center().open(); //Set the Window to the center of the screen.Need to change it here.

        var data = $('#stimi2').html();
        var fontSize = parseInt($("#stimi2").css("font-size"));
        fontSize = fontSize + 10 + "px";


        $('#divText'+question+'-'+tries).html(data);
        $('#divText'+question+'-'+tries).css({'font-size':fontSize});

        $('#ImageTry').val(tries+1);
    }
```